# Silverlight Browser App to Desktop App

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight, web-applications, desktop-application

I saw this Silverlight application  that works inside the browser but if you clicked Install it will be downloaded on your machine and runs as Desktop Application how this can be done !!
http://os75.com/apps/Translator.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is now a [feature in Silverlight 4](http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/silverlight-4/#whatsnew). Quote:

> The .NET Common Runtime (CLR) now
>   enables the same compiled code to be
>   run on the desktop and Silverlight
>   without change.

To get it working you'll need Visual Studio 2010 and the Silverlight 4 SDK. Then, when you create a new project you open settings from the Solution Explorer and check the "Enable running application out of browser" check box on the Silverlight tab. There are a few extra settings for icons and such available in a separate dialog launch-able from a button right under the check box.

Comment: If you have a tutorial on how to make that please provide me with it

Comment: See my addition to my answer above. You don't really need a tutorial. It's just a matter of enabling the feature in project properties.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done because ever Silverlight app that can be installed is [Sandboxed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_%28software_development%29)

Comment: Can you give me a tutorial or something smiler of how to make this

Answer (score 1):

Out-of-Browser Support:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dd550721%28VS.95%29.aspx